# Odds of drawing a number in a lottery

Tags: probability

I am busy designing a game and would like to offer my players odds based on balls drawn from a lottery.

Here is an example:

A player picks 2 balls form a pool of 1 - 50.
The game auto picks 5 balls from a pool of 1 - 50.

What are the chances of the player matching 2 of the 5 balls drawn?

Comment: With or without replacement?

Comment: Once a ball is drawn, it is taken out the pool. So the first ball would be 1/50 and the second 1/49

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the two events (the two balls being drawn and the five balls being drawn) are independent, we can change their order:

So, five balls are drawn from a pool of fifty.

Let us examine what must happen for the player to get two out the five balls: First, one of the five correct balls must be drawn, then one of the four remaining. So the probability of drawing two correct balls becomes $$\frac{5}{50}\cdot\frac{4}{49}=\frac{2}{245}.$$

Comment: Ha.. that makes sense... thank you!